# Dedicated SQL Server instance for SQL Agent

Tags: sql-server

I have an environment that has dozens of SQL Server instances all running SQL agent jobs for their own maintenance as well as other processes (ETL, etc.). I am considering a change to consolidate the non-maintenance jobs to a separate SQL Server instance(s). I'm thinking that having the SQL Agent job processing setup on centralized servers would be easier to manage and coordinate jobs' schedules. I would also plan on using one of these SQL Agent only instances as the distributor for replication purposes.

Besides licensing concerns what downside would there be to move to such a configuration?

Comment: I'd be concerned about one server going down causing dozens of ETL processes to grind to a halt.

Comment: PowerShell is probably a more appropriate method to manage multiple SQL Servers/Agents without any changes to the config. You can refer to [this post](http://stuart-moore.com/adding-sql-server-jobs-using-powershell/) on adding jobs via powershell and [this mssqltip](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1798/checking-sql-server-agent-jobs-using-windows-powershell/) about reporting on agent jobs as points of reference. PowerShell is pretty powerful and meant for managing multiple servers, its not just for the OS.

Answer (score 5):

A: every job query will require four-part names.

B: that Agent's  credentials will require privileges on *all* instances which is a security risk.